# How to create rugged/feathery cloth in Blender

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, 3d-printing

I am trying to create a dress using blender or marvelous designer(export to blender) for a 3D character that will be suitable for both 3D printing(main objectice) and basic animation, possibly even use in Unity3D.

The idea for the dress is that it's skirt is made out of long feathers but still looks and functions as a skirt.
Also the skirt of the dress is not meant to be hanging on the character, but behave more like a Victorian dress supported by a corset.

I study through practice and currently my problem is that I have little idea of how to efficiently approach the problem without wasting days on trial and error.

A great help would be a technique, tutorial, or anything that can nudge me towards the right approach from where I would be able do further reading.

Here are some similar examples from internet of what the texture of the dress should look like:[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe look into tutorials about hair, you can create hair with curves that have bevel objects, then convert to mesh and boolean?

Comment: Ya that makes sence and I could be using bones for main curves and some of plugins aimed at animating hair. However I found situations with a lot of intersecting curves to be poorly handled by blender booleans and need a lot of further clean-up. I will make attempts at using curves, however will still be looking for some more cloth based solutions.

Comment: once you have converted your curves to meshes you can give them cloth simulation, also you can give a Mesh Defom modifier to your feathers and use a cage that will have the cloth simulation.

Comment: you have a lot of tutos like this one, to me these feathers look exactly like this kind of hair and you can simply animate with cage (Lattice, Mesh Deform or Surface Deform): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMU_fa1G-bA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same technic as for modelling hair: Create some curves with a bevel object. Once you're good, convert to mesh, merge your meshes into several objects:

[image]

To animate you can give your feathers physics, either cloth simulation or soft body. To make it lighter to calculate you can assign the simulation to a cage and give your feathers a *Lattice, Mesh Deform* or *Surface Deform* modifier, like that for example:

[image]